# vue-router-multiguard respects asynchronous guards

Tags: asynchronous, vue-router

Does anyone have experience with [vue-router-multiguard](https://github.com/atanas-dev/vue-router-multiguard)?

The documentation says "Guards are executed serially in the order they are supplied, respecting asynchronous ones. "

But looking at the code I don't see how it could do so.
Anyone able to help me see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the library responded to me on [github](https://github.com/atanas-dev/vue-router-multiguard/issues/7#issuecomment-658686665)

> async behavior is achieved via the next callback parameter. The guard chain will not proceed until the current guard calls it even if it is called in an async manner. Here's the [README.md](https://github.com/atanas-dev/vue-router-multiguard/blob/master/README.md) example which uses setTimeout to demonstrate async behavior in guards